# How to extract public DBlink with ora2pg

Tags: postgresql, oracle, dblink, ora2pg

My understanding is that ora2pg is capable of extracting private Oracle DBLinks inside a schema.
How about public DBlinks (in DBeaver, I see them under `Global metadata/Public Database Links`)?

If I specify a schema in the config file and run this command, no DBLink is found (as excpected, because no private DBLink is set inside this schema):

```
ora2pg -t DBLINK -o dblink.sql -b ./schema/dblinks/ -c ./config/ora2pg.conf
```

If I comment the schema in the config file (to target all schemas) and run the same command, I get this error:

```
FATAL: ORA-20000:
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 347
ORA-24237: object id argument passed to DBMS_UTILITY.INVALIDATE is not legal
ORA-06512: at line 2 (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtExecute)
```

Is there a way to extract a public DBLink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/config/ora2pg.conf`, you just need to put `PUBLIC` for the schema name:

```
# Oracle schema/user to use
SCHEMA PUBLIC
```